# Using react-native-aws3 to upload to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I am uploading images to s3 using the react-native-aws3 library.  the component is RNS3.
I successfully upload and I am able to access the url and view the image, however, I am unable to find the object in my S3 bucket using the AWS console.  here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, Image} from 'react-native';
import {region, bucket, accessKey, secretKey} from '../auth';
import image from '../assets/background.png';
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';

const upload = () => {

    const file = {
        uri : 'file:///Users/ayunas/Documents/lambda/cooking-recipe-source-control-fe/CookingRecipesExpo/assets/background.png',
        name : 'my_logo.png',
        type: 'image/png'
    }

    console.log(file.uri);


    const options = {
        keyPrefix : "public/",
        bucket,
        region,
        accessKey,
        secretKey,
        successActionStatus: 201
    }

    RNS3.put(file, options)
        .progress(event => {
            console.log(`percent: ${event.percent}`);
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 201) {
                console.log('response from successful upload to s3:', res.body);
            } else {
                console.log('status code: ', res.status);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error uploading to s3', err)
        })
}

const get = () => {
    Storage.get('amir.txt')
        .then(res => console.log('result get', res))
        .catch(err => console.log('err getting', err))
}

function ImageUpload(props) {

    return (
        <View style={{alignItems : 'center'}}>
            <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100}} source={image} />
            <Text>Click button to upload above image to S3</Text>
            <Button title="Upload to S3" onPress={upload}/>
            <Button title="Get from S3" onPress={get}/>
        </View>
    )

}

export default ImageUpload;
```

any insights into how to find the image in the AWS console?  I can click on the res.location and navigate to the object using the URL.  but that's about it.

Comment: Did you refresh the console? There is an actual refresh option in the S3 console UI. It can hide things if not refreshed.

Comment: Looks like it is showing up in the S3 buckets now.  Not sure why it wasn't before

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh the console? There is an actual refresh option in the S3 console UI. It can hide things if not refreshed.

Comment: Looks like it is showing up in the S3 buckets now. Not sure why it wasn't before.  Thanks @rodrigo M

Comment: As I say, likely needed a refresh.